# field is resetting to 0 when document is getting updated

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have a field for duration which is calculated based on the time user enters while creating a document. This duration field is being stored in firestore along with other fields.

Now when i am updating document, other fields are getting updated but this duration field is resetting to 0.

i am loading these fields from firestore;

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  duration = widget.data.duration;
  time 1= widget.data.time1;
  time 2= widget.data.time2;
}
```

Update code (edit is firestore collection)

```
edit.update({
          'Time1': Time1,
          'Time2': Time2,
          'durationoftime': durationOfTime,
```

Comment: in your update button wrap with setState and reset you duration to zero

Comment: from where do you take the value for durationOfTime?

Comment: @AshiqUllah initially when i am loading page, i am getting from firestore and later calculating based on time 1 and time 2.

Comment: so, here is the problem. Check what your calculation returns and does your calculation logic update the value of durationOfTime. Usually, updating value needs to have setState(). I would like to see how do you calculate and update your durationOfTime.

Comment: @AshiqUllah calculations are working fine. Here is the scenario, in edit page when i change the values, it is calculating fine. But on edit page, if i don't change the time and only update some other field, time is resetting to 0. it's like it is ignoring the already entered time values.

Comment: I wish I could see your logic, UI, or source code.